# geom_abline does not fit with geom_dotplot in ggplot2 R package

Tags: r, ggplot2

The question relates to ggplot2 R package. Why is the intercept of the geom_abline off by the amount of the slope when drawn with the geom_dotplot? Try the following examples:

```
testdata <- data.frame(predictor = c(0,1), dependent = c(0,2))

testplot <- ggplot(NULL) +
             geom_dotplot(data = testdata, aes(x = factor(predictor), y = dependent), binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center") +
             geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 2))
testplot #The line is off

testplot <- ggplot(NULL) +
             geom_dotplot(data = testdata, aes(x = factor(predictor), y = dependent), binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center") +
             geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0 - 2, slope = 2))
testplot #The line aligns with the dots as expected
```

Is this a bug or me doing something silly? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? It's not clear from these two points. When you use `factor()`, R will recode values to map each unique value to an integer starting at 1. So your values of 0 and 1 become 1 and 2 when plotting. Normally you wouldn't use `factor()` with values that are already numeric. You could just use `group=` in the dotplot instead: `geom_dotplot(data = testdata, aes(x = predictor, y = dependent, group=predictor), binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center")`

Comment: Also `?geom_abline` reveals that `Unlike most other geoms, these geoms do not inherit aesthetics from the plot default, because they do not understand x and y aesthetics which are commonly set in the plot. `  So, maybe that's why the second `testplot` is working for you.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for your quick help. My aim was to align the dotplot (measurements) with the abline (model representing the measurements) on the same coordinate. The 0 -> 1 recoding by the `factor()` solved the issue. I need `fill = factor(cluster)` for coloring clustered data more complex than shown in the above example. Anyhow, I continue substracting the slope from the intercept to realign the geom_abline, if there is no way to control how the `factor()` works.